# django template, String management

Tags: django, django-templates

I have several template that use limited number of string many times, so I'm thinking of reusing strings in some way instead of hard coding in templates.

I found two way, but both of them has limitation, so I'm asking of better way to do this or probably standard way to managing String in Django templates.

**First and simply**: Storing them in Database, it works well if I create a simple model below and send all of them in views (about 500 objects), for all rendered template. Further more I can categorize them, and send just related category in each template.

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField()    
    trans = models.TextField()
    type = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=string.types)
```

#### Pros:

- simplicity
- even users with admin access can manage them, and there is no need to me for changing simple text
- can store translation (for future, if more languages needed)

#### Cons:

- increasing database access
- fear of unknown security issues

**Second: using `{% with x="done" %}` tag** I can use "with" tag in base template, and extend it in other templates, so i have access to all of tag with standard django.

#### Pros:

- simple
- no DB access
- probably safe

#### Cons:

- with tag need all of it its entry in one line then it is useful to
  maximum of 10-20 entry, far away of 300-500 entry
- managing in html
- hard coding

#### EDIT:Third, Using [Django translation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/)

Thanks to @Danial Roseman's comment I can use i18n.

#### Pros:

- most standard way till now

#### Cons:

- complicated as managing hard coded strings :)
- overhead (according to i18n document)

Comment: One possibility that springs to mind is to use the [translation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/) support; you can store all your strings in a message file and refer to it by a short name in the template.

Comment: @Prakhar Please don't spam me. I don't know anything about scrapy in any case.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just store your strings in a dict (let's call it 'strings') that you pass into the context using a context processor and then use the standard `{{ strings.key }}` notation. No security issue, no database required, no special management needed and you can mark your strings as translatable as well if you need it.

Comment: Seems well, let me give it a try and will give feedback soon as i can